# Only Let Friends/Public See Mutual Friends

Tags: facebook, privacy

I am wondering how would I modify my privacy settings on Facebook so that my friends/public would only see our mutual friends, and not a list of all my friends and the number I have?

On a side note, is there a way to modify your settings so that when you change your relationship status (i.e., break up with someone) that it will not announce to everyone?

Comment: I assume you are talking about facebook?

Answer (score 3):

To modify your friend list privacy, click on the list of your friends on your time line (friends block). In the new page, on the top right section click on Edit and then specify who can see your friend list on your timeline. Limiting this to "Only Me" will not let anyone else to see your friends. Other people will be able to only see mutual friends if they have not limited their friend list privacy.

[image]

To edit the privacy of your relationship status, click on "About" on your timeline below your profile picture. In the new page, click on Edit button of "Basic Info" block and edit the relationship status privacy by specifying who can see your relationship. Change it to "Only Me".

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me what to do so no one in Public can see my albums?